# What will be captured by the C# Entity Framework linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, closures

When implementing specification pattern I came up with this code

```
public static class ItemSpecification
{
    static public Expression<Func<Item, bool>> TodayOnlySpecification { get; } = item => item.ImplementationDate == DateTime.Today;
}
```

This expression will later on be used in EF linq filters for building queries. My question is, what date is actually used in the query. Is it the date that the static class is first initialized? Or the date that `TodayOnlySpecification` is referenced?

A concrete scenario would be

1. My application starts up today and I reference `TodayOnlySpecification` the first time for a linq query, it should use today's date for the eventual sql
2. My application kept running and I reference `TodayOnlySpecification` again tomorrow for another linq query, will today's date be used in the query or tomorrow's date be used?

Edit 1:

Testing with `DateTime.Now` and `DateTime.Today` yields very different results

1. `DateTime.Now` produces the following SQL query:

   ```
   select ... 
   from ...
   where [Extent1].[ImplementationDate] = (SysDateTime())
   ```
2. `DateTime.Today` produces the following SQL query:

   ```
   select ... 
   from ... 
   where [Extent1].[ImplementationDate] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0='2019-06-11 00:00:00'`
   ```

This is just a guess, the fact that linq to entity is able to translate `DateTime.Now` to `SysDateTime()` means it is not using the value of `DateTime.Now` for translation. Instead, it is using the method to get the current time when generating SQL. This should also mean that `DateTime.Today` is captured as an method not a value.

Edit 2:

This then brings another question, if EF sometimes evaluates a method at the client side (e.g. `DateTime.Today`) and sometimes evaluates at the server side (e.g. `DateTime.Now`), which could be having a different timezone, how can one determine the exact behavior of EF queries?

Comment: I'd suggest using `DateTime.Now` and testing it for yourself. You'll see very quickly if / when the value changes.

Comment: Exactly. When you tested it (you _did_ test it before you posted your question, didn't you?), what happened? Was it what you wanted to happen? What you expected to happen? Why or why not?

Comment: Note that in general, lambda expressions are going to capture variables, not values. But, the use of EF _might_ complicate matters, depending on when the expression is evaluated. That's really more an EF question though than a LINQ, lambda, or closure question (i.e. your question is grossly mis-tagged).

Comment: @mjwills good idea. Should have tested with DateTime.Now. I was too worried about spending two days testing with DateTime.Today

Comment: Also you could have tested this by profiling your DB, with DateTime.Now

Comment: @PeterDuniho In general. But there are no variables to capture ;)

Comment: Typically one would create another question when asking follow on questions.

Comment: @Aron: _"there are no variables to capture"_ -- correct. So nothing is actually captured in the given example. The "in general" I was actually referring to is the fact that in the context of something like EF, the expression will eventually get translated into something useful in a query, and the timing and mechanism of that may affect the evaluation of the expression in the lambda and its relationship to that query. In plain vanilla C#, such a lambda would evaluate `DateTime.Today` every time the expression is invoked (e.g. as delegate), but EF could cache a result.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Actually the EF.SqlServer handling code is referenced in my answer. In this case it is replaced with a SQL call, dependent on the version of SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What gets captured is

```
Expression.Call(
    null, //Static call so no instance
    methodOf(DateTime.Now),
    new Type[0] //No generic arguments
);
```

In otherwords. Nothing gets captured.

I recommend you use the debugger to examine the `IQueryable<T>.Expression` to look at the tree.

EDIT:

To answer your question on how EntityFramework handles the above expression. It doesn't. It is upto the implementation of EntityFramework Provider to handle.

In the Case of EntityFramework.SqlServer, the code that handled this is located here

[SqlFunctionCallHandler.HandleCanonicalFunctionCurrentDateTime](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlGen/SqlFunctionCallHandler.cs) line 1259